# Vagrant ignores tags if i specify them in ansible configuration

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I have a very simple ansible configuration:

```
- name: Prepare and intsall RethinkDB on available machines
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - { role: rethinkdb, tags: ["install"] }
```

And a corresponding vagrant config:

```
universe.vm.provision "ansible" do |a|
  a.playbook  = "configuration.yml"
  a.groups = {
    "primary"   => ["rmaster"],
    "secondary" => ["rsecondary"]
  }
end
```

The problem is if i call `vagrant provision` ansible runs `rethinkdb` role ignoring specified in `configuration.yml` file `install` tag. Though it works if i put it into vagrant as `a.tags = "install"`, but it won't work if i have a sequence of ansible tasks to run with different tags, so i'd like to specify them from ansible playbook.

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what behaviour you are expecting? Are you trying to run only tasks with the `install` tag, or only certain roles?

Comment: @RégisB. Yes, i have a role `rethinkdb` and there are tasks tagged as isntall, configure, launch, etc... I want Vagrant to run them separetely

Comment: Have you found an answer to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible for a playbook to define the role tags that will be run by the role. What `tags: ["install"]` does is to *assign* the `install` tag to the tasks from the `rethinkdb` role ("[you may wish to assign tags to the roles you specify](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles)").

If your install, configure, launch, etc. tags are run in sequence, then you should be able to dispatch them to different (possibly [dependent](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies)) roles. If not, then your only other solution is to run individual tasks using not tags but variable values.

E.g:

in `roles/rethinkdb/tasks/main.yml`:

```
  - name: my_task
    when: run_rethinkdb_install
```

in `playbook.yml`:

```
- name: Prepare and intsall RethinkDB on available machines
  hosts: all
  vars:
    run_rethinkdb_install: True 
  roles:
    - { role: rethinkdb, tags: ["install"] }
```